# jQuery clone() row return origin value or ajax call only fetch row 1?

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value, clone

I've build a table with add/del row function.
Then those rows ( origin and duplicated ) are fetched, transform into JSON and sent via ajax call to my django server.

but the problem is that the value of the origin's row are kept on the cloned one and I'm not too sure where the fault is.

Having some reviews on my code could help me solve this problem.

here my code source:

```js
//the add row function 
// I've make sure that the value is not cloned into the future row

$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(e){
  $('#del_row').prop('disabled',false)
  // console.log('add clicked')
  var index = $('.duplicable').length
  var newId = '#duplicable'+index;
  var row = $('#duplicable').clone().attr("id",newId).find(':input').prop('value', '').end();
  $('#Attributes_table tbody').append(row);
});

//then the actual ajax function 
$(document).on('click', '#product-submit', function(e){
  var attrs = [];
  $('.duplicable').map(function(){ 
    attrs.push({
         'id' : $(this).attr('id'),
        "finition": $('.finition').val(),
        "size": $('.size').val(),
        "price": $('.price').val(),
        "img": $('.img').val(),
    })
  }).get();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url :  window.location.pathname,
    data : {
      'ajax_post' : 'create_product',
      'designation': $('#id_designation_input').val(),
      'description': $('.editor-content').text(),
      'selected_ttag': $('#id_product_select_ttag').val(),
      'selected_ctag': $('#id_product_select_ctag').val(),
      'selected_otag': $('#id_product_select_otag').val(),
      'attr': JSON.stringify(attrs)
        
      },
    success : function(){
      console.log(attrs)
      
    },
    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
      console.log(xhr.status + ":"+ errmsg+ err)
    }

  });
});
```

here is the print output:

```bash
ajax_post create_product
designation 
description 
selected_ttag 
selected_ctag 
selected_otag 
attr [{"id":"duplicable","finition":"black","size":"S","price":"19.99","img":"C:\\fakepath\\certificats.png"},{"id":"#duplicable1","finition":"black","size":"S","price":"19.99","img":"C:\\fakepath\\certificats.png"}]
```

and here is the actual input

[image]

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the clone() function the problems lies in the construction on my dict before the ajax call